# Rearrange strings columns in R

Tags: r, string, substring

I have some string observations to reorder such that they follow the model(nbexp1) below

```
nbexp1 <- c('no 1b', 'xyz Str', 'close to xyz', 'Abeokuta','Ogun state')
```

i.e strings containing numbers comes first, then strings containing 'Street' or 'Str' or 'Road' or 'Rd' comes second, followed by those containing 'close' or 'near', followed by the locations (Abeokuta, Ilara, Sango) then the State (Ogun).
How do i create a function to transform the following observations in R

```
nbexp2 <- c('cbd Street near', 'ogd', 'Ilara', 'Ogun State')
nbexp3 <- c('18 xyz road','near to ogd busstop', 'Sango otta', 'ogun state')
nbexp4 <- c("Uche compd", "no 2 along laderin", "Abeokuta ogun state")
```

Comment: The first step would probably be to write a function that returns something like a rank for a given string based on your criteria. In your case, something like: 1 if the string contains a number, 2 if it contains "St" or "Street" etc. Once you have that you can use `order` or `sort` and use a vector of your self generated ranks as the sorting criteria.